# Rebus of handwritten characters

Tags: visual, rebus

What does the following image signify?

[image]

*It is hand-drawn in MS Paint so it may not be legible.*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My guess is:

> Half time

because:

> the image is the top half of the word 'TIME'

Comment: That is correct. I am a little disappointed someone solved it so quickly

Comment: But all the same really well done

Comment: @DeltaScuti_Fomalhautb - you should at some point accept the answer and mark the question as solved

Comment: @JeffZeitlin  Sorry I did that now